# Window constantly reloading after calling JavaScript reload function

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript reload function to reload my page. The function is working but the issue is the page is getting reloaded for every second continuously.
I am using window.location.reload();
even if use location.reload(); same problem I am facing .

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're running the reload function on the page, then when the page is reloaded, the reload function is run again, and the cycle repeats.

Comment: Sounds like your reload function is called infinitely on every page load. You need to set up a cancel mechanism via sessionStorage or localStorage

Answer (score 1):

You need to run that function on any event rather then body onload or page onload
Please add that function on any button click event or something.

**Here is an example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            HTML DOM Location reload() Method
        </title>
          
        <!--script to reload current page-->
        <script>
            function locationreload() {
                location.reload();
                  
        }
        </script>
    </head>
      
    <body>
        <h1>Testing 123</h1>
          
        <h2>
            HTML DOM Location reload() Method
        </h2>
          
        <p>
            Click on the button to reload the document
        </p>
          
        <!-- script call here -->
        <button onclick = "locationreload()">
            Reload page
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```